# how to take a variable number of rows and place each row in seperate columns in libre office

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have about 1,200 rows and I am trying to put them into columns after every twenty rows.  How would I do this with out manually copying and pasting a hundred times?  Also, I would like to add the values of each resulting column and take the average.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

There probably is a way to do this in LibreOffice, but I think it'd be simpler to use a scripting language for this, e.g. `Perl`. Save the sheet to a text file (e.g. `input.txt`) and run the following command:

```
 perl -ne '
   BEGIN{ $i=0 }
   chomp;
   if (defined $arr[$i]) {
     $arr[$i] .= ",".$_;
   } else {
     $arr[$i] = $_;
   }
   $i = ($i + 1) % 20;
   END { print join "\n", @arr }
 ' input.txt > output.csv
```

Import `output.csv` in LibreOffice.

Comment: This was a good idea.  I used PHP and averaged every twenty numbers.  I found out the csv syntax to make a new column.  While commas divide each value into a new cell, a carriage return divides the next values into a new column. I would still like to know how to directly do this in libre office

Answer (score 1):

You can probably do this with the " =OFFSET() " function in Excel, or since you're using Libre Office it has something similar called " =INDEX() " I think.

Comment: I would need something more specific.  Thanks